# getting the position from the png image of LUDO game

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

hy 
i am working on a game in android i.e LUDO Game.
i used four different array of getting the positions of the LUDO Board on Hit and trail mwthod.

Four different arrays are as follow.

```
    int[] t_LM = { 60, -44, 17, -46, 155, -44, 17, -46, -201, -44, 17, -46,
        155, -44, 17, -46 };
int[] t_TM = { 42, 63, 63, 85, 42, 63, 63, 85, 233, 254, 254, 275, 233,
        254, 254, 275 };
int[] t_o_LM = { 38, -57, -57, -57, -57, -57, 3, -27, -27, -27, -27, -27,
        3, -27, -27, -27, -27, -27, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, -27, -57, -207, 3, 3,
        3, 3, 3, -57, -27, -27, -27, -27, -27, -57, -27, -27, -27, -27,
        -27, -57, -57, -57, -57, -57, -57, -27, 3 };
int[] t_o_TM = { 200, 275, 275, 275, 275, 275, 305, 337, 369, 401, 432,
        464, 464, 464, 432, 401, 369, 337, 305, 275, 275, 275, 275, 275,
        275, 242, 209, 209, 209, 209, 209, 209, 177, 146, 115, 83, 51, 20,
        20, 20, 51, 83, 115, 146, 177, 209, 209, 209, 209, 209, 209, 242 };
```

The image of the LUDO board are as follow
[image: Actual board of the game]

but when i get the coordinates and maps on the Screen of the emulator it shows like this..

[image]

The box with pink,yellow and green shown in the pictures are the coordinates i got after Hit and trail method.

any software or link that help to fix this problem are highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is, at least for me, totally impossible to understand your problem...

Comment: You need to take care of each mobile screen density.

Comment: Formula for Rectangular shape. Local picture coordinates to mobile phone coordinates
Where pVertices[0] = px;
pVertices[1] = py;
public void transformLocalToScene(final float[] pVertices) {
  int count = pVertices.length / 2;
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  while(--count >= 0) {
   final float x = pVertices[i++];
   final float y = pVertices[i++];
   pVertices[j++] = x * this.a + y * this.c + this.tx;
   pVertices[j++] = x * this.b + y * this.d + this.ty;
  }
 }

Comment: hi.i am facing problem in ludo game development.i am not able to move tokens as per dice roll.like if dice displays 2 then token will move two position forward.can you give me idea about it.thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to move the `pink, yellow and green tiles` on the top of `white squares` which are part of a `background image`.

I am not sure if you can get the specific coordinates`(belonging to white boxes)` of the image at run time. `(Please comment, if it is possible. I would love to learn)`

My alternative would be, when you roll a `dice` let the user touch the specific `white box` and draw the `colored tile` over it.

Else, you can draw you own board `programmatically` or through `xml` and change the color of the `white box` to the color of the `user tile`

Comment: i am not sure about setting coordinates at run time but i am doing it statically. i want to set these colored tiles on the white boxes but i need to get the locations of the boxes so that ican set them accordingly. Kindly suggest any idea how can i achieve it

Answer (score 0):

You can use aspect ratio to resolve this issue. Take the dimensions of the original image by hand, measure some initial positions of pieces from original image, get dimensions of image on run time, calculate aspect ratio of original and onscreen image and place pieces using that ratio at run time.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to set the pieces on the ludo board image to show the user's progress throughout the game.

The way you are doing that it can be done by managing the aspect ratio and placing the pieces accordingly, which is quite tough, and can't predict if it will actually work or not. If you want to use naive android, use a `15x15`  grid and break the image accordingly. Later use the grid positions as co-ordinate for your colored pieces.

If you are searching for easier options, use Game Engines like Unity, but it may create a larger size APK file for your game.